# How to Remove the First Occurrence of a duplicate Value in Array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have a group of an array

```
Array ( 
[0] => 0
[1] => 1
[2] => 1 
[3] => -1 
[4] => 3 
[5] => 0 
[6] => 2 
[7] => 3
[8] => -2 
[9] => 2 
[10] => 0 
[11] => 1
[12] => 1 
[13] => 2 
[14] => 5 
[15] => 0 )
```

And i want to delete the values of this array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 3 
[1] => 1 
[2] => 2 
[3] => -1 
)
```

But i want to preserve some of the duplicate data.. I just want to delete one occurence of the second array..

The Result would be like this:
EXPECTED RESULT

```
Array ( 
[0] => 0
[2] => 1 
[4] => 3 
[5] => 0 
[6] => 2 
[8] => -2 
[10] => 0 
[11] => 1
[12] => 1 
[13] => 2 
[14] => 5 
[15] => 0 )
```

How can i do that?.. array_unique and array_diff is removing all the occurence of the value in the first array..

Comment: You mean you dont want the data to be repeted adjacently??

Comment: i just want to delete the first occurence value that comes from the array2.... if you notice from the expected result.. the total number of 1 in the array is 3 only.. But the original array1 the total number of 1 value is 4... so it just delete the first 1 value

Comment: Do you need array keys to be kept as in original array?

Comment: Nope, the value of the array only is the important

Comment: Is there an error in your expected result? Shouldn't `[4] => 3` be deleted instead of `[7] => 3`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, try the following (Your script should define the $first_array and $second_array variables):

```
foreach ($second_array as $to_delete) {
      $key = array_search($to_delete, $first_array);
      if ($key !== FALSE) {
          unset($first_array[$key]);
      }
}
```

Comment: this will return error.. because the second parameter is not array.. in array_search.. the $to_delete

Comment: i notice something there is one value here that returns -1... all of the data is correct but the -1 is not deleted... is that possible?

Comment: Great :) please take your time to mark that I gave you the right answer :}

Answer (score 1):

Another one

```
<?php
$source = array(0, 1, 1, -1, 3, 0, 2, 3, -2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 0); 
$items_to_filter = array(3, 1, 2, -1);
$result = array_filter($source, function ($var) {
                global $items_to_filter;
                $index = array_search($var, $items_to_filter);
                if($index !== FALSE)
                {   
                        unset($items_to_filter[$index]);
                        return false;
                }   
                return true;
          }); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like,

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($a1); $i++)
{
  if(in_array($a1[$i], $a2)) {
    for($j=0; $j<count($a2); $j++)
      if($a2[$j] == $a1[$i])
        unset($a2[$j]);

    unset($a1[$i]);
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this so there maybe errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(0,1,1,-1,3,0,2,3,-2,2,0,1,1,2,5,0);
$delete = array(3,1,2,-1);
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (in_array($val, $delete) && in_array($val, $result)) {
        unset($delete[$val]);
    } else {
        $result[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => -1
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 2
    [6] => -2
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 2
    [11] => 5
    [12] => 0
)
```

P.S.: if you want to delete an element of $delete array even if there's only 1 occurence of it then replace

```
if (in_array($val, $delete) && in_array($val, $result)) {
```

with

```
if (in_array($val, $delete)) {
```

Comment: this one also return -1... [2] => -1... What do you think this one?.. it's not deleted

Answer (score 0):

This approach should run faster than the `array_search()` or `in_array()` approaches because it avoids a linear search through the array on each iteration:

```
function del_first_found($array, $todel) {
    $todel = array_fill_keys($todel, true);
    $newarray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($todel[$value])) {
            unset($todel[$value]);
        } else {
            $newarray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $newarray;
}

$input = array(0,1,1,-1,3,0,2,3,-2,2,0,1,1,2,5,0);
$to_delete = array(3,1,2,-1);
$result = del_first_found($input, $to_delete);
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach - without using the lame unset function - would be:

```
foreach($values as $v)
{
    array_splice($array, array_search($v, $array), 1);
}
```

This removes the first occurrence of each value in `$values` from your `$array`.

An example-code in PHP:

```
$array = array("a","a","b","c","b","c","d","d","e","d");
$values = array("b","c","f");

array_walk($values, function(&$v,$k) use(&$array){array_splice($array, array_search($v, $array), 1);});

echo implode(",", $array);
```

Will output:

```
a,b,c,d,d,e,d
```

Answer (score -1):

array2[i] is the value from array2 that you want to delete

```
$value = array_search($array2[i],$array1);
if($value)
{
    unset($value);
}
```